# Add multiple Bundles inside a single Bundle in C# MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, bundling-and-minification

For Example I Want to Create Bundles like this

```
/*These are my Two separate Bundles*/

bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/MYBundle1").Include(
           "~/Content/css/style.css"));

bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/MYBundle2").Include(
           "~/Content/css/media.css"));

/*Now i want to use above two bundles as a single bundle */

bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/AllPageBundles").Include(
           "~/Content/MYBundle1",
           "~/Content/MYBundle2")
```

Also I want to ask that can i add reference of any file inside a bundle that is physically exist at any site server
For Example:I want to add google fonts file inside a bundle like i write bellow

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/MYBundle1").Include(
               "http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300"));
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For multi-bundles you can write like:

For directories:

```
 bundles.Add(new Bundle("~/js/core").IncludeDirectory(@"~/Scripts/Infrastructure/JQuery", "*.js")
                                                     .IncludeDirectory(@"~/Scripts/Infrastructure/Knockout", "*.js")
                                                     .IncludeDirectory(@"~/Scripts/Infrastructure", "*.js"));
```

For files:

```
 bundles.Add(
                new Bundle("~/js/kendo").Include("~/Scripts/kendo/kendo.core.min.js")
                                        .Include("~/Scripts/kendo/kendo.data.min.js")
                                        .Include("~/Scripts/kendo/kendo.binder.min.js")
                                        .Include("~/Scripts/kendo/kendo.calendar.min.js")
```

For url try this code:

```
var jqueryCdnPath = "http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300";
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("myfoobundle", jqueryCdnPath).Include("~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));
```

Comment: When I use first example .IncludeDirectory everything works fine but I've noticed that it doesn't minify the file but when I include multiple files using .Include it minifies. Is there any special parameter that i need to include?

Comment: no minifiy in debug mode, set to false in web.config

Answer (score 0):

To add a sub directory with all it's content you can use another overload of IncludeDirectory() method that set to search & add all sub folders too.

```
bundles.Add( new Bundle( "~/js/core" ).IncludeDirectory( 
            @"~/Scripts/Infrastructure/JQuery", "*.js", true ) );
```