# Bundling in asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, bundling-and-minification

I'm using bundling in an ASP.net MVC application. I want to build my bundles in a hierarchical fashion.

For instance, these are the scripts I want on all my webpages:

```
 bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap-js").Include(
                                         "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                                         "~/Scripts/respond.js",
                                         "~/Scripts/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js",
                                         "~/Scripts/jquery.smartmenus.js",
                                         "~/Scripts/jquery.smartmenus.bootstrap.js"
                                         ));
```

Next I want to have for example knockout on only some pages:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/knockout-js").Include(
                                "~/Scripts/knockout/knockout-3.4.0.js",
                                "~/Scripts/knockout/knockout-kendo.js",
                                "~/Scripts/knockout/knockout.mapping-latest.js",
                                "~/Scripts/knockout/knockout.validation.js",
                                "~/Scripts/knockout/knockout.validation.de-DE.js",
                                "~/Scripts/knockout/knockout.validation.fr-BE.js",
                                "~/Scripts/knockout/knockout.validation.nl-BE.js",
                                "~/Scripts/knockout/Knockout.bindinghandlers.js",
                                "~/Scripts/knockout/knockout.validation.mvc.js"));
```

And finally, I want every page to have it's own custom script.

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/scriptName-js").Include(
                                "~/Views/Cards/scriptName.js"));
```

Is there a way so I only have to include one @scripts.render statement by combining all previous bundles in to one bundle?

```
 @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/mypage-js")
```

I tried this but it didn't work:

```
 bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/mypage-js").Include("~/bundles/scrip‌​tName-js","~/bundles‌​/knockout-js","~/bun‌​dles/bootstrap-js"))‌​;
```

Comment: You can look into this post http://stackoverflow.com/a/31808683/1662459

Comment: Just Include them under a single bundle ID

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work:  bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/mypage-js").Include("~/bundles/scriptName-js","~/bundles/knockout-js","~/bundles/bootstrap-js"));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an [overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj646482(v=vs.110).aspx) of `Include` that accepts an array of paths instead of a `params` of paths.  You can use this to define blocks of shared scripts as `string[]` and then include them:

```
var everyPage =  new [] {
    "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
    "~/Scripts/respond.js",
    "~/Scripts/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js",
    "~/Scripts/jquery.smartmenus.js",
    "~/Scripts/jquery.smartmenus.bootstrap.js"
};

var knockout = new [] {
    "~/Scripts/knockout/knockout-3.4.0.js",
    "~/Scripts/knockout/knockout-kendo.js",
    //etc...
};

bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/scriptName-js")
  .Include(everyPage)
  .Include(knockout)
  .Include("~/Views/Cards/scriptName.js")
);
```

It's not quite as succinct as referencing one bundle from another but it's better than repeating every block of scripts